# Запятая между то и что

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Где нужно поставить запятые в предложении "И что, то что знал?"

Answer (score 3):

> где запятые в этом предложении "и что, то что знал?"

Лучше "то" выкинуть:

***И что, что знал?***

==============

Можно с частицей "ну":

***Ну и что, что знал?***

Answer (score 2):

Если это реакция на неполно выраженное утверждение "То, что знал - плохо", такое выражение грамматически возможно, но только как цитата:

```
И что "то, что знал"?
```

Менее резко можно переспросить так:

```
И что в том, что знал?
```

Answer (score 1):

Без контекста совершенно непонятно, что эта фраза может значить, а потому и знаки предсказать трудно.
Варианты:
***"И что-то, что знал".*** - с этим понятно.

-Я сказал, все что знал.
***-И что, то, что знал?***
-Не помогло.

**И что? То что знал?**

@Alex_ander еще вариант понимания дает.
И другие можно придумать....

Answer (score 0):

1. Неверно поставлен падеж слова "то" и сочетание "то, что" не отделено запятой. Вот и всё. "И что в том, что знал?". А запятой надо отделять, ведь "то" - местоимение, "что" - союзное слово/союз (здесь: союз).